# generate random 0 or 1 - Oracle

Tags: oracle, random

I need to generate a random value that can be 0 or 1. I tried this: `select floor(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 1)) from dual` but there is a very very very low possibility of get value 1. Is there any chance to get this where the possibilities for 0 and 1 are similar?

Comment: Why not `round` rather than `floor`?

Comment: `select round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 1)) from dual` ?

Comment: Yes @JustinCave you are right, round do the trick. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `round` instead of `floor`:

```
select round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (0, 1)) from dual
```

Answer (score 4):

`DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,1)` will *never* return 1. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_random.htm#i998095):

> low   The lowest number in a range from which to generate a random
>   number. The number generated may be equal to low.
>
> high   The highest number below which to generate a random number. The
>   number generated will be **less than** high.

You want: `floor(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,2))`

Answer (score 3):

Use DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM to get an integer, and `mod (n,2)` to get 0 (even number) or 1 (odd number)

Comment: This is ok, but i getting value -1 too when i do this: `mod(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM,2)`, i need to use `abs`, am i right?